# Timeline bar with colour/fill based on time-series' value (R ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

I've got a time-series data frame with pressure readings taken at regular intervals.

```
                  time   pressure        diff
1 2014-09-09 09:12:29  1.6191598  0.00000000
2 2014-09-09 09:12:28  3.0137784 -0.07668387
3 2014-09-09 09:12:27  1.1958183  0.58693260
4 2014-09-09 09:12:26  2.2803681  1.07774954
5 2014-09-09 09:12:25 -0.7614310 -0.17864232
6 2014-09-09 09:12:24  0.9914106 -0.70121973
```

I can easily make a line plot of the pressure using ggplot2. But below this line plot, I'd like to have a horizontal bar where the fill colour depends on the pressure differential between two consecutive samples (df field `diff`).
For example, the bar would be white at times where the pressure differential is zero (i.e. pressure has not changed bewteen two consecutive samples). The fill colour would go towards a deeper shade of (say) red as the differential increases positively, and blue as it increases in the negative values.

generate sample data:

```
 dfTimeSeries <- data.frame(time = Sys.time()-seq(1:10), 
                            pressure = rnorm(10,1), 
                            diff = c(0,diff(dfTimeSeries$pressure)))
```

First part of the plot

```
 ggplot(data = dfTimeSeries)+
     geom_line(aes(x=time, y=pressure))
```

How can I code this horizontal bar that would span along the entire x (time) axis and whose fill colour would vary based on the on the  `diff` field of my df for the corresponding timestamp?

Comment: I just thought I could use `geom_rect()` to draw rectangles side-by-side on one horizontal line, and set `aes(  [...]  fill=diff)`?
Is there a better way ?

Comment: `geom_rect` is certainly how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting `geom_rect` objects side-to-side, one rectangle for each value of `diff`. Here's the basic concept:

```
ggplot(data = dfTimeSeries)+
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=pressure))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmax=time+.5, xmin=time-.5,ymax=-3,ymin=-2, fill=diff))
```

I'd need to to adjust the colour scale, fit the bars in a different graph, and do a bit more cosmetic arrangmeents, etc.

[image: Pressure plot and colour-coded differential band]